# Asp.NET MVC ModelBinder, getting Action Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I got a custom ModelBinder and i would like to get the action. Because i want to get the Attributes of the action using reflection, the action name is not enough.

my action method:

```
[MyAttribute]
public ActionResult Index([ModelBinder(typeof(MyModelBinder))] MyModel model)
{
}
```

and here a typically ModelBinder

```
public class MyModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) 
    {
        // here i would like to get the action method and his "MyAttribute"
    }
}
```

any suggestions, other solutions ?

many thanks in advance

Comment: Is this `MyAttribute` an action filter or a plain CLR attribute? What's its purpose and why do you need to *tie* it with the model binder?

Comment: Yes, the MyAttribute is a CLR Attribute. I would sign the method with "informations" because there is no way to pass arguments with [ModelBinder(typeof(MyModelBinder))].

Comment: @dknaack, there is a way: you could use a custom model binder provider.

Comment: Could you provide a sample ? I don't think that's this will solve my problem.

Comment: @dknaack, I need to first understand your problem and what you are trying to achieve. When those values need to be passed to the model binder? Are they specific to the current action? I am not sure I understand the benefit of using this custom attribute. What value does it bring? Why is it needed by the model binder? Can't the model binder fetch those values from somewhere else. A concrete example of what you are trying to do would suffice for me to understand your scenario and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes those values are specific to the current action. For example, i have a model with 2 Properties and i want tell the ModelBinder which of them should be validated.

Comment: @dknaack, why are you performing validation in your model binder? Also now that I understood your problem here's the solution to it: use View Models. So each action will accept it's own specific view model containing only the properties that are required by this action. You could then apply validation attributes to the corresponding properties.

Comment: Yes i know ;) That was only a example. The problem is that i have values that are specific to the current action. Is there no way to pass arguments to a modelbinder ?

Comment: @dknaack, what those values represent and why do you need to pass them to the model binder? I am sure there is a better way to achieve what you are trying to do. It's just that I need to understand what you are trying to do first so that I can provide you with a solution :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot with 100% certainty get the current action from a model binder. The model binder is not coupled to the action, but to binding to a model. For example, you can call

```
TryUpdateMode(model)
```

In an filter before an action has been chosen. Also note that an action method might not even be a CLR method (see http://haacked.com/archive/2009/02/17/aspnetmvc-ironruby-with-filters.aspx) that can be reflected on.

I think the real question is, what exactly are you trying to accomplish and is this the right way? If you want information from the action to be passed to the model binder (heeding the advice that your model binder should degrade gracefully if the information isn't there), you should use an action filter to put the information in HttpContext.Items (or somewhere like that) and then have your binder retrieve it.

An action filter's OnActionExecuting method receives an ActionExecutingContext which has an ActionDescriptor. You can call GetCustomAttributes on that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Phil! I know that it is not coupled (saw it using System.Diagnostics.StackFrame). It is hard to describe what i want to do in a comment. I will now do it using a ActionFilter and blog about my solution later. If you interested i send you a link via twitter if my blog post is done.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
var actionName = controllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
var myAttribute = (MyAttribute) Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(controllerContext.Controller.GetMethod(actionName), typeof(MyAttribute));
```

Comment: I tryed that before. But i could have many methods with that name and different arguments. So "controllerContext.Controller.GetType().GetMethod(actionName);" will result in a System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException

Comment: of course if the signature of your your action contains only MyModel you can use controllerContext.Controller.GetMethod(actionName, new[] {bindingContext.Model.GetType()}); But this probably won't be enough

Comment: Yes, that's not enough ;) I could have to methods with that and other differences in the arguments.
thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You could override `ControllerActionInvoker.FindAction()` to get the action's attribute and store it in `HttpContext.Current.Items` as mentioned here, or extended`ControllerContext.RequestContext`, as follows:

```cs
public class MyControllerActionInvoker : ControllerActionInvoker
{
    protected override ActionDescriptor FindAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, ControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, string actionName)
    {
        var action = base.FindAction(controllerContext, controllerDescriptor, actionName);

        if (action != null)
        {
            var requestContext = ExtendedRequestContext.Bind(controllerContext);
            var attr = action.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();

            if (attr != null)
                requestContext.CustomAttribute = (MyAttribute)attr;
        }

        return action;
    }
}

public class ExtendedRequestContext : RequestContext
{
    public MyAttribute CustomAttribute { get; set; }

    public static ExtendedRequestContext Bind(ControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        var requestContext = new ExtendedRequestContext
        {
            HttpContext = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext,
            RouteData = controllerContext.RequestContext.RouteData
        };

        controllerContext.RequestContext = requestContext;
        return requestContext;
    }
}
```

The default action invoker is replaced either in your controller's constructor or in a custom controllers factory:

```cs
public MyController() : base()
{
    ActionInvoker = new MyControllerActionInvoker();
}
```

By the way, `Controller.TempData` already contains an item of `ReflectedParameterDescriptor` type, which gives you access to `ActionDescriptor`, so the above code may be redundant. However, beware this is implementation specific, so may change over time.

Finally, get the attribute from that storage in your binder class:

```cs
var requestContext = (ExtendedRequestContext)controllerContext.RequestContext;
if (requestContext.CustomAttribute != null)
{
    // apply your logic here
}
```